# Automating mouse position

Tags: macos, mouse, automation

Is there anything in AppleScript, Automator, Swift or anything else I can program which would allow me to set the position of the mouse?

My plan is to find a way of moving the mouse to the centre of the screen. I have multiple screens, and sometimes I can’t find the mouse without a lot of fiddling. (I know I can shake it and see a larger version, but it’s still not obvious enough). I can centre it with a keyboard shortcut, it would be perfect.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=applescript+cursor+position